# My resultMap does not work when I use annotations rather than mapper xml

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis, ibatis

I have a module in my project that is using ibatis Annotations. I need to use a storede procedure in this module that returns one string value and one resultMap(array).

```
    <resultMap id="oldNinsMap" type="com.evry.reseptformidleren.webservice.vo.IdentChangeVo">
        <result property="oldNin" column="nin"/>
    </resultMap>
    <parameterMap id="getIdentChangeParameters" type="map">
        <parameter property="INNIN" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="RESULT_OUT" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="OUT"/>
        <parameter property="oldNins" jdbcType="CURSOR" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet" mode="OUT" resultMap="oldNinsMap"/>
    </parameterMap>
    <update id="sp_IdentChanged" parameterMap="getIdentChangeParameters" statementType="CALLABLE">
        {call PKG_IDENTITY_CHANGE.SP_IdentChanged (?, ?, ?)}
    </update>
```

And I'm trying to do the same using annotations but it is only returning null.

```
    @Results(id = "oldNinsMap",
            value = {
                    @Result(property = "oldNin", column = "nin")
            })
    @Update(value = {
            "{call PKG_IDENTITY_CHANGE.SP_IdentChanged (" +
                    "#{INNIN, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR, javaType=String }," +
                    "#{RESULT_OUT, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR, javaType=String }, " +
                    "#{old_nin, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, resultMap=oldNinsMap}" +
                    ") }"
    })
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
    Map<String, Object> sp_IdentChanged(Map<String,Object> paramMap);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should declare the result map separately (e.g. in a XML mapper). `@Results` works with `@Select`, but not with `@Update`. Also note that the values of OUT parameters would be set to the `Map` passed to the method (in other words, the method may not return value).

Comment: @ave for this project we where trying to not use XML mapper. But I ended up using a normal select instead of using the stored procedure.
The stored procedure is returning 1 value in Result_Out and an array in old_nin. Is there a way to do this using only annotations?

Comment: @TorePetersen Did you find a "annotations only" solution?

Comment: No sorry ended up changing the storede procedure to return my data is an different way so did not need it.